# Is there a name for $x^T M y$?

Tags: linear-algebra

When $x$ is a real vector and $M$ is a real symmetric matrix, $x^T M x$ is called a "quadratic form". Is there a specific name for $x^T M y$ where $x$ and $y$ are real vectors and $M$ a real matrix?

Comment: It is called [*bilinear form*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form)

Comment: in this case, a ***symmetric*** bilinear form, because the transpose of a one by one matrix, i.e. a number, is itself, $$   \left( x^t M y\right) =   \left( x^t M y\right)^t = y^t M^t x = y^t M x.  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Bilinear Form".

It very much depends on the context: for example if you have:

$$z(x,y)=x^TMy$$

then $z(x,y)$ is bilinear in $x$ and $y$ (exactly the same way as $h(x)=x^TMx$ is quatratic in $x$)